# row time differences calculation and concatenation by mutual element in column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My DF looks the following:

```
action  value   created_by     created
ADD       A      Steven     10/2/20    6:46 AM
ADD       B      Steven     13/2/2020  6:55:18 AM
ADD       E      Steven     13/2/2020  6:57:30 AM
ADD       C      Steven     13/2/2020  7:00:10 AM
ADD       D      Steven     18/2/2020  7:07:39 AM
Remove    B       Ana       19/2/2020  7:17:12 AM
```

I would like to create a new DF based on the mutual elements in the `value` column and perform  operations if the same element has both ADD and Remove actions.

Iif the element in the `value` column has both ADD and Remove action, then
both `action` and `created_by` will be merged (strings), the time difference in days will be calculated, and the new DF will have the following row:

```
Action     value     created_by         day_difference
Add-Removed   B    Steven-Anastasia           6
```

Thought of using group by + apply on some lambda function but couldn't get it done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This only makes sense if there can only be two of the same `value`, one with `add` and one with `remove`
- Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with a `agg` function for each of the columns

  - There's a custom function to calculate the time difference
- `created` must be a `datetime` dtype.

  - Use `df.created = pd.to_datetime(df.created)` if `created` is not a `datetime` dtype.
- The `day_diff` column will be a [`pandas.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html#pandas-timedelta), unless the option to return a `float`, is uncommented in `def day_diff`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

# test data and dataframe
data = {'action': ['ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'Remove', 'ADD', 'Remove'],
        'value': ['A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'F', 'F'],
        'created_by': ['Steven', 'Steven', 'Steven', 'Steven', 'Steven', 'Ana', 'Steven', 'Ana'],
        'created': [pd.Timestamp('2020-10-02 06:46:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-02-13 06:55:18'), pd.Timestamp('2020-02-13 06:57:30'), pd.Timestamp('2020-02-13 07:00:10'), pd.Timestamp('2020-02-18 07:07:39'), pd.Timestamp('2020-02-19 07:17:12'), pd.Timestamp('2020-02-13 06:55:18'), pd.Timestamp('2020-02-19 07:17:12')]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# if created is not a datetime column, uncomment the following line
# df.created = pd.to_datetime(df.created)

# display(df)

   action value created_by             created
0     ADD     A     Steven 2020-10-02 06:46:00
1     ADD     B     Steven 2020-02-13 06:55:18
2     ADD     E     Steven 2020-02-13 06:57:30
3     ADD     C     Steven 2020-02-13 07:00:10
4     ADD     D     Steven 2020-02-18 07:07:39
5  Remove     B        Ana 2020-02-19 07:17:12
6     ADD     F     Steven 2020-02-13 06:55:18
7  Remove     F        Ana 2020-02-19 07:17:12

# function to calculate created_diff
def day_diff(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Timedelta:
    time_diff = x.iloc[1] - x.iloc[0]
#     time_diff = round(time_diff / timedelta(days=1), 3) # uncomment if created_diff should be returned as a float
    return time_diff


# get the groupby object
dfg = df.groupby('value')

# create a list for the selected groups matching the condition
df_list = list()

# iterate through dfg and select for len == 2 and actions is both ['add', 'remove']
for g, d in dfg:
    actions = sorted(d.action.str.lower().unique().tolist())  
    if (len(d) == 2) & (actions == ['add', 'remove']):
        dg = d.groupby('value', as_index=False).agg({'action': '-'.join, 'created_by': '-'.join, 'created': day_diff}).rename(columns={'created': 'day_diff'})
        df_list.append(dg)
        
df_combined = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)  # combine the list of dataframes

# display(df_combined)

  value      action  created_by        day_diff
0     B  ADD-Remove  Steven-Ana 6 days 00:21:54
1     F  ADD-Remove  Steven-Ana 6 days 00:21:54
```